# I'm slick of duplicates ([slick.js], [slick-carousel] and [slick-js])

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I'm not sure if bad puns in titles are accepted to non burninate-requests, so sorry about that.

I stumbled across a jQuery plugin called [slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) which is a jQuery carousel. I noticed, that Stack Overflow seems to have three tags associated to this plugin:

- [slick.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slick.js) (<del>75</del> 121 questions)
- <del>[slick-carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slick-carousel) (42</del>) (all retagged)
- <del>[slick-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slick-js) (4 questions)</del> (all retagged)

All three tags indicate in their info page that they're about the same plugin. I thought all the questions from the two last tags could be edited to change their corresponding slick tag for [slick.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slick.js), since it seems to be the most popular tag of the three and has the most detailed about page, even though it's not the oldest one.

Comment: ooh that pun was slick.

Comment: I upvoted this purely because of the title.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a good pun?  The standard reaction to any pun is a groan isn't it? :-)

Comment: Nice, I actually read that as "I'm sick" for a second there

Comment: Are punny titles required for initiation into the meta brotherhood?

Comment: @Jamen I think it's called the "meta fatherhood".

Comment: Time to start a project called *sick.js*.

Comment: @kapa That would actually be a badass name. Away with jQuery, away with knockout.js, here comes **sick.js**!

Comment: The way people keep punning is slickening

Comment: I love how none of the comments have been about the tags and what we should do with them, but all about the pun in the title (which was nicely done by the way)

Comment: What happens if you mark two of them as synonyms of a third one?

Comment: @TylerH I didn't know about this possibility. However, I'm afraid I can not do that.

Comment: I've got the best name, and it's my real name.

Comment: @kapa: It's [already here](http://vanilla-js.com/) for those who are sick with unnecessarily used JavaScript libraries.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Germany has been researching into puns (https://www.ukp.tu-darmstadt.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Group_UKP/publikationen/2015/2015_Miller_Disambiguation_of_English_puns.pdf) so they should be able to tell you the appropriate reaction

Answer (score 10):

I faced the issue few months back and I created the slick.js tag. I even modified bunch of questions, but looks like people have added more since then.

My reasoning for using slick.js was simple, "slick" is the name of library and ".js" signifies it is a JavaScript library. Since it is used for creating carousel, many people have created the alternate tag that should be merged. That detail should go into the tag description.

A lot of these questions were simply tagged `slick` when I checked, which is not what I was looking for. I wanted to use slick tag for **Scala Language Integrated Connection Kit**. Now that is real slick. It deserves the tag.

Thanks for noticing this. I wasn't alone.