# Synonymize [slick-slider] and [slick.js] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

It's been two years since [the three tags joined together](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299817/), and now the fourth one has appeared.

I propose to make the [slick-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slick-slider) tag a synonym for [slick.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slick.js). Its description confirms that it's about the same plugin.